# Unidentified sign using php substr

Tags: php, character, substr

My code is:

```
$desc = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $product->post->post_excerpt);

$desc = strip_tags($desc);

$desc = html_entity_decode($desc);

echo substr(trim($desc),0,235);

echo "...";
```

Represent the text with ? Unidentified sign at the end of the string

[image]

Comment: How did you get this string?

Answer (score 0):

Try `mb_substr` instead to fix the diamond question mark issue,

```
echo mb_substr(trim($desc), 0, 235,'utf-8');
```